# How to add an '--' option in upstart exec

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I've been using redis-commander but now I need to start it automatically on boot up.
I used upstart to make this happen but problem is it ignores the "--" option. I'm doing it like this.

```
script
    exec /usr/local/bin/redis-commander --redis-password M+4IZ3hZy7/cf7
end script
```

Seems like it ignores the --redis-password options since I got this error

```
 Redis error Error: Ready check failed: ERR operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're passing long options, I believe you need the `=` sign between option and value. Try this:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/redis-commander --redis-password='M+4IZ3hZy7/cf7'
```